System $ e^{-t}\frac{dx_1}{dt} = -x_1 + x_2$, $ e^{-t}\frac{dx_2}{dt} = -x_1 - x_2, $ w/ $x_1(0) = 1$ and $x_2(0) = 0$.
How to solve system
$$
\begin{align}
e^{-t}\frac{dx_1}{dt} &= -x_1 + x_2\\
e^{-t}\frac{dx_2}{dt} &= -x_1 - x_2
\end{align}
$$
with the initial conditions $x_1(0) = 1$ and $x_2(0) = 0$?
I only solved problems with constant matrix but here system has a matrix of the form
\begin{pmatrix} -e^t & e^t \\ -e^t & -e^t \end{pmatrix}
Thank you.

Hint. $\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d}{ds}$. Choose $s$ such that $\frac{ds}{dt}=e^t$. This will give you a system of ODEs with constant coefficients.

@Moo It will be very useful if you provide the solution. Thank you .

@neelkanth: I take it back - not possible in this case.

This system can be written as
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2\end{array}\right)'=
e^t\left(\begin{array}{rr} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2\end{array}\right)
\quad\text{or}\quad x'=e^{t}Ax,
$$
where $x=\left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2\end{array}\right)$ and $A=\left(\begin{array}{rr} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1\end{array}\right)$. Then
the general solution of the system is
$$
x(t)=e^{(\int_0^t e^{-s}\,ds)A}x(0)=e^{(1-e^{-t})A}x(0)
$$
where
$$
e^{tA}=e^{-t}\left(\begin{array}{rr} \cos t & \sin t \\ -\sin t & \cos t \end{array}\right)
$$
Hence the solution of the IVP is
$$
x(t)=e^{e^t-1}\left(\begin{array}{rr} \cos (1-e^{-t}) & \sin (1-e^{-t}) \\ -\sin (1-e^{-t}) & \cos (1-e^{-t}) \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right)
$$

Using complex numbers.
Set $z=x_1+ix_2$, then
$$
z'=x_1'+ix_2'=\mathrm{e}^t\big((-x_1+x_2)+i(-x_1-x_2)\big) \\
=\mathrm{e}^t\big((-x_1-ix_1)+(x_2-ix_2)\big)
=\mathrm{e}^t\big(-(1+i)x_1+(1-i)x_2\big)
=-(1+i)\mathrm{e}^t(x_1+ix_2)=-(1+i)\mathrm{e}^tz
$$
Thus
$$
x_1(t)+ix_2(t)=z(t)=z(0)\exp\left(-(1+i)\int_0^t \mathrm{e}^s ds\right)
  =(1+0i)\exp\left(1-\mathrm{e}^t\right)
\exp\left(-i(1-\mathrm{e}^t)\right)
$$
$$
=\exp\left(1-\mathrm{e}^t\right)\left(\cos(1-\mathrm{e}^t) -i\sin(1-\mathrm{e}^t) \right)
$$
and finally
$$
x_1(t)=\mathrm{e}^{1-\mathrm{e}^t}\cos(1-\mathrm{e}^t), \quad
x_2(t)=-\mathrm{e}^{1-\mathrm{e}^t}\sin(1-\mathrm{e}^t)
$$

Thank you ........
